# How to add an asp.net web api application to IIS (the proper way)

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.et web api application, which until now I have deployed to the IIS default web site. I am now seeing that this is bad practice, as is putting it under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

So, I want to understand 100% how to manually set this up in IIS with the proper relationship between web sites, applications, bindings, and application pools. Most of it actually makes sense except for the web site vs application.

I have found plenty of tutorials, but I just can't believe how many just don't work (and some even suggest changing port 80, for http, to something else!). So leaving SSL out of the equation for now, I followed a tutorial (which didn't work) as follows.

1. I put the application somewhere other than under wwwroot, so I have put it at say `C:\inetpub\myapp`
2. The tutorial now says to crate a **web site** and point it to here. So I do this in IIS manager
   [image]
3. According to the tutorial I should now be able to go to site.com in the browser. This does NOT work, it times out. It turns out I need to a add this to the the **hosts** files, ie add the entry

   127.0.0.1 site1.com

Now when I browse to site.com, and I see the default IIS page, (not the default.html of my application)

4. So, I add it as an application...

[image]

5. I now browse to `http://site1.com/myapp`. I get

   ```
   Server Error in '/myapp' Application.

   Configuration Error

   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

   Parser Error Message: The configSource file 'config\throttlePolicy.config' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed. 

   Source Error: 


   Line 57:   </system.serviceModel>
   Line 58:  
   Line 59:   <throttlePolicy configSource="config\throttlePolicy.config" />
   Line 60:   <appSettings configSource="config\appSettings.config" />   
   Line 61:   <connectionStrings configSource="config\connectionStrings.config" />    

   Source File: C:\inetpub\myapp\web.config    Line: 59
   ```
6. Finally I nest the app folder within the site folder, ie `C:\inetpub\myapp\myapp`

[image]

NOW finally, if I browse to `http://site1.com/myapp/` I can see my app!

**QUESTION**

Have I done this the right way?

Nowhere seems to mention you need to nest the app in the site folder?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake you're making is that you need to create a virtual folder or application *under the existing Default Web Site*, rather than creating a whole new web site. You should be right clicking 'Default Web Site' and creating things under there rather than right clicking the web server root

Let me address things as I come across them. Everything below is a simplified explanation and there is a lot more to it but will hopefully help.

> > I am now seeing that this is bad practice

Bad practice with regards to web sites is often around security. i.e. don't leave obvious guessable defaults that make it easy to hack

> > some even suggest changing port 80, for http, to something else

This is an example of a guessable default. 80 is the default web port. If you change it to something else, it means that a DOS attack on port 80 will fail because there is no web server listening on it.

> > I put the application somewhere other than under wwwroot

Good idea.

Often when building an application you put all the application code on a different drive (i.e. D) so that C is purely the OS and in theory you could reinstall it or move D drive completely if you had an issue.

> > create a web site and point it to here

A lot of the confusion here is around terminology - you don't actually want to right click / create website in the root. That creates a whole new 'host' level website. You want to right click on the 'Default web site' and create one of the following:

- If you have nothing but static content (html pages, images, javascript), then create a *virtual directory* (doesn't have an application pool)
- If you actually have server side processing (i.e. an ASP application) you Add an *Application* (which has an application pool)

Here are some of the things that make up a website (with reference to IIS)

1. A Server running IIS
2. The Server in turn contains one or more 'Web Sites' which represent a 'root' respond to a certain host name and port. By default you have the *Default Web Site* that you see in IIS. At this stage you probably shouldn't be creating new 'Web Sites' at this level.
3. The 'Default Web Site' in turn contains one or more virtual folders or applications. These are the folders under 'Default Web site'. This is where you actually need to publish your web site files

You need to be focusing on level 3 here but it looks like your doing things at level 2

That's why you just get an IIS default page - you created a whole new root web site, rather than an actual 'application'

If you had a couple  of different web applications running on a web server they would *normally* be in their own seperate 'web application' folders rather than creating a root web site per application.

> > I should now be able to go to site.com in the browser. This does NOT work

`site1.com` doesn't exist on the internet (which is where your browser is looking). Nor does it exist on the 'LAN' until you make the change to the hosts file. This is a networking / DNS thing which I won't go into.

> > So, I add it as an application.

Yes. You need to skip straight to this step, but create it under the Default Web Site

> > I now browse to http://site1.com/myapp. I get...

The config error you get is related to creating things at the wrong levels. Delete everything in IIS (except Default Web Site), and start again!

> > Nowhere seems to mention you need to nest the app in the site folder?

I understand your frustration. It's not really explained anywhere. (I just googled for an explanation of the different levels and couldn't find anything).

When you're starting out with web apps in IIS you should generally have one 'Default Web Site' with multiple 'Applications' and 'Virtual folders' under it.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. So, from what I understand, the only reason for wanting another "web site" would be if you want to use a **completely different URL to address it**, for example if you were to DNS register a completely different URL.So, If I had an internal intraweb app just addressed by its internal IP, I would have this in a separate **web site** to another app that may be outward facing with it's own DNS registered URL. So, same base URL -> Same web site, different URL then I need to do the different site with the "nested app"?

Comment: Yes. Or you can use it to run a website on the same host with a different port. Or you can do this thing called binding where your URL has a different hostname but it actually goes to the same host but IIS picks it up